# Alert box cannot block the request in Firefox6

Tags: firefox, alert

For preventing the submit button's double click, I wrote the following function which is called on the form's `onsubmit` event.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var submitFlag = false;
function checkForm(){
    if ( submitFlag == false ) {
        submitFlag = true;
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('double click');
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<form name="f1" method="post" action="B.jsp" onSubmit="return checkForm()">
```

In Internet Explorer, when I click the submit button twice the alert method occurs. If I don't click the okay button in the alert box, the jsp is not redirected.

However in Firefox6 the alert box is very fast and I have no time to click the ok button. The jsp is redirected very fast and the second request has been sent out.

How can I block the request from going through in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button.

```
onsubmit="document.getElementById( 'submitbuttonid').disabled = true;"
```

Since FFx4 (Gecko 2) they redone the boxes system, so it is no longer an actual alert/prompt/confirm box, this was done for security of the user, so there's no abuse of the boxes.

Comment: oh!From ff4 is sing tab-modal prompts.I set prompts.tab_modal.enabled to false for using the window-modal prompts.The second request is blocked,but the box is stopped in the B.jsp.Your idea is the best.Thank you very much indeed! :)